# Why does new Date(undefined) create an invalid date, but new Date(null) does not?

Tags: javascript

I noticed something odd today with Javascript:

```js
console.log(new Date(null)); // 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(new Date(undefined)); // Invalid Date
```

Why is this the case? I know null and undefined are not the same, but in this context I would expect the same result.

Comment: As far as I can infer, calling `new Date(null)` is equal to calling `new Date(0)`. Calling `new Date(undefined)` possibly ends with adding up undefined (as number for milliseconds) and resulting to NaN which is an Invalid Date (calling `new Date(NaN)` obviously returns 'Invalid Date'). But I'm not sure of my theory, can someone clarify this?

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value you can see ToNumber() ends up being called, for null this is fine and is `0` but for undefined its NaN.

Comment: Seems my theory was correct. @AlexK. you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `new Date` gets called with a single primitive argument that is not a string, it will cast it to a number. And while `null` will coerce to `0`, `undefined` will become `NaN`, and that's the internal value of the date you're getting back.

```js
console.log(null + ":")
console.log(Number(null))
console.log(new Date(null).valueOf())
console.log(new Date(null).toString())
console.log(undefined + ":")
console.log(Number(undefined))
console.log(new Date(undefined).valueOf())
console.log(new Date(undefined).toString())
```